# How to save a dictionary as a value of another dictionary in pymongo for flask?

Tags: python, dictionary, pymongo

I have a `Json` request that looks like this:

```
{"name":"jane", "family": "doe",
"address":{"country":"Iran", "State": "Ilam", "city": "ilam"},
"age": "25" }
```

and i can get the values into a variable using:

```
name = request.json['name']
family = requst.json['family']
age = requst.json['age']
```

but, how do i get the address field and save it to a variable?

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking. You just demonstrated how to access data in a dictionary. What is the difficulty?

Comment: how do i get the address field in a variable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have the following dictionary, 'address' is a dictionary that is nested in another dictionary:

```
{"name":"jane", "family": "doe",
"address":{"country":"Iran", "State": "Ilam", "city": "ilam"},
"age": "25" }
```

Extracting the address is done in the following way:

```
address = request.json['address']

>>> address
{'country': 'Iran', 'State': 'Ilam', 'city': 'ilam'}
```

Address that you extracted is now a new dictionary, and you need to extract values from it like this:

```
state = address['State']
city = address['city']
country = address['country']
```